# How to create an array from an object to render data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I'm converting an object into an array but TypeScript throws and error:

> "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'"

(Yes, I googled that error but nothing very clear on the web)

[**Live Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqbgnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In this live demo you will not see the **TypeScript error** but in my Angular app I can see it and it's causing issues.

How can I convert this object to the same array shown on my live demo using Lodash or JavaScript?

This is the code:

```
dataObject = {
A: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mike', lastname: 'asmith'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mary', lastname: 'alters'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Boris', lastname: 'al'}
],
B: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Lauren', lastname: 'bmith'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Travis', lastname: 'balters'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Barn', lastname: 'bl'}
], 
...
}
  
dataObjectDisp = Object.entries(this.dataObject).reduce((prev, [key, value]) =>{
  return [...prev, ...value.map((user, index) => ({ 
    ...user, parent: key, index }))]
}, []);
```

This is the output that I want:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mike",
    "lastname": "asmith",
    "parent": "A",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mary",
    "lastname": "alters",
    "parent": "A",
    "index": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: What is your ES version? Check that you have ES2017 as it was introduced in same.

Comment: value is type of object and map is only available if it is an Array.

Comment: Try to add type to `value`. Change `[key, value]` to something like `[key, value]: [string, Array<{ id: number; name: string; lastname: string; }>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS can't infer the type of `Array.reduce()` accumulator (the empty array at the end). You can set the accumulator as the type of array you wish to get in the end ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOAeQwEkNh4BfOAMyjTgHIABAQwwHMBXAG1agD0AY2hZGAbgBQk5qnTZcACgSS4cAM5YeWITGgAuJiACeAWlZgwjPKrgws4PvYCqUHocYA6ARbCeR8jgwngAWMCA81rbqMMbarjzqhgDaTN6%20-miQCsFC6uqMcAC6kpQAlNKxYFhEAEYAVnAAvIi2AETAACZthhhcILVYUDZqbRisIFg9GjBQwJwjcG18MeOT0zFzC%201g-EEbs-Mcix0YnVgAHtN9A0OlUpKXkLBwQivqcACClnLZQXCgMDaSa4D7EMgUVpqTqsGCsQgNHTwFoqNRqT4pWxotEILqGACMBDWWA8AFlgABrMQEFYwYkeVjqEAUEKMSiLbFqXGdQwAJiJExJTFJ-GM1jgtPpTFYPHsUAK7KxnO5hgAzALJh4AELQYAFGmMumChmRShKoocuBazGcnF4uCEuBSxgAGVYXCgOHFkuNTFqzJgrMVtq59v5Tt9jAAKlBWAA3PXew3O2oyuUKy3YlVwdURzVMLX8DBJ1aR2qm81Ks3YmFwhH1JEAET1YGadQbuk8QTmWHUikDes8tfhiN0ZU8ns6XCEWEUijAnrjBGSVOMBDjMq4WCKZWaAD5UZzPTAPRg4MlPJeF1gl3BL54Nzwt54QBY51xNMMAWdLrumnu4GUOAlWxe8PyGAhdk9XBDFXAh5nOC44HKMoSmxdlzyKOBGXbZId2kJVOHBcgYEUXdD2xEQMHUCBtE8HgIA4fsQkHYd6ybFsyikdDSkkIA)):

```
type Obj = {
  "id": number,
  "name": string,
  "lastname": string,
  "parent": string,
  "index": number
};

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
  dataObjectDisp = Object.entries(this.dataObject).reduce((prev, [key, value]) =>{
    return [...prev, ...value.map((user, index) => ({ 
      ...user, parent: key, index }))]
  }, [] as Obj[])   
...
}
```

Another option is to use `Array.flatMap()` instead of array reduce, but you'll need to change the target in TS Config to es2019 ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOAeQwEkNh4BfOAMyjTgHIABAQwwHMBXAG1agD0AY2hZGAbgBQk5qnTZcACgSS4cAM5YeWITGgAuJiACeAWlZgwjPKrgws4PvYCqUHocYA6ARbCeR8jgwngAWMCA81rbqMMbarjzqhgDaTN6%20-miQCsFC6uqMcAC6kpQAlNJYAB6QsHBCfPlwAIKWctlBcKBg2iBB6kSk5PAqagAmrDCshABGAFY68AC8iLZqzSlratsIwGOGAIwEGKx9HgCywADWYgSNMCdnTKzqIBQhjJQ22z%20Ie4YAJmOpywF34xmscHuj1Bzx49igBS%20Wx%20u32cAAzMCnowAELQYAFO4vB4gjysSKULZFb7bXGbX47f5wI5wGEeAAyrC4UBwkOhZKYMzeMA%20yMZajRgOxsMYABUoKwAG6E-kk9lCikIpG0xlSzEyjy4-gYNUxDWMGaU6lbKk-LYTKazBa6AAihLAcBWzsWniCUGAWHUilFhM8jum80WZU8NCc5wsikUyRuxgISopXCwRTKXoAfCi4BmeFnPCBE4ouJooARgBgxtVc0s83BlHBPB2q1ga3AwPwgoZU7X69U4OUKj8KltOMQyBRFLnRr8RBh1BBtJ4eBAOCGQmGIz63R6ylIflSqUA)):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
  dataObjectDisp = Object.entries(this.dataObject).flatMap(([key, value]) =>
    value.map((user, index) => ({ ...user, parent: key, index }))
  )
...
}
```

And if you use lodash, you can use `_.flatMap()`, without changing the target ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOAeQwEkNh4BfOAMyjTgHIABAQwwHMBXAG1agD0AY2hZGAbgBQoSLES0%20MALKswcanQaMeEACasAzgAsJkyc1TpsuABQJJcOAaw8sQmNABcTEAE8AtKpgjHgOcDBY4IpYAKpQPN6MAHQCQUkiVjgwSUYwIDwhYQYwvq5xPAbeANpMKWkZkNbZQgYGjHAAupKUAJRmWAAesvBCfK1wAIJgYJaNWXAyriBZBkSk5PD2jvowrIQARgBWbvAAvIhhjhPVl453CMC63gCMBBisy4lKwADWYgRjGDvT5MQwgCgmSihO4wxCPbwAJjeHywX34vhCcEBwNRoJ4ESgbShtxhDyecAAzMiQYwAELQYBtAGGIEoxKsAqUW4daF3Wk3WH3eFwV5wHGJAAyrC4UBwmOxbKY%203BMEhvMFZMR1NxjAAKlBWAA3RnylnipUcglE9WwzWU7WJWn8DCm4rmxj7Tnc25cmG3HZ7I4nAAijLU5xoihUYBsqsZSQDB2O7gINkNHK4WAIf18PTgpwAfCS4OmeJmkiBVDYbFxnFACMAMLpBnnC3A7HAkl3a1h63AwPwst4cw2m4N1D0%20jC%20rdOMQyBQbHmtrCRBgDBBXEkdBxY0Z44mg%205QwYwD0pDCuVygA)):

```
import { flatMap } from 'lodash';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
  dataObjectDisp = flatMap(this.dataObject, (value, key) =>
    value.map((user, index) => ({ ...user, parent: key, index }))
  )
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through objects keys and get your result this way

```js
var dataObject = {
  A: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Mike',
      lastname: 'asmith'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Mary',
      lastname: 'alters'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Boris',
      lastname: 'al'
    }
  ],
  B: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Lauren',
      lastname: 'bmith'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Travis',
      lastname: 'balters'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Barn',
      lastname: 'bl'
    }
  ],
};

const convert = (obj) => {
  var result = [];
  for (var key in obj) {

    result = result.concat(obj[key])
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(convert(dataObject))
```